# Casting of down votes decrements reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, answers, down-votes

I have seen many times that sometimes when I downvote a post , my repuation decrements by -1 and sometimes it does not?

What is the reason behind it?

And what are the exact scenarios when this happens?

Comment: Downvoting answers costs 1 rep; question downvotes are free.

Comment: Downvoting an answer costs 1 rep. Why? So people won't just downvote "competing" answers on a post. It also shows that we find answers to be more valuable than questions.

Comment: It also shows that there are more bad questions than bad answers, and we want to encourage people to downvote them without worrying over a few lost points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Downvote a question: no penalty.

Downvote community wiki: no penalty. (Thanks to J.Steen)

Downvote an answer: -1 rep.

Comment: But its does not happen for every answer?

Comment: ....? It should....

Comment: It doesn't happen for Community Wiki answers.

Comment: Thanks @J.Steen. I'll add that in.

Comment: @J.Steen - Heh. I never knew that.

Comment: @Oded Wooah. =D